# Google Colab ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import Altair but I get this error message. I tried installing markupsafe and altair using the !pip option but anything seems to work.

ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/markupsafe/**init**.py)

Comment: `pip install altair` works perfectly for me - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12GBRCd6AljtgCIkq8P5gcaQjslIuJoEm?usp=sharing